# Handling composed objects in UML activity diagrams

Tags: uml, composition, simplify, activity-diagram

### Intro

When designing UML activity diagrams I often encounter a rather simple problem for which I have to draw a rather complicated solution. I'm looking for an UML conform shortcut or more simple solution for the following problem.

### Problem

Lets assume we have a class **Parent** with associations to different Children:
[image]

And we have an analog Constalation with the class **Result** and three chidren **Result Part A**, etc.

Now I want to refine an activity, which accepts a **Parent** object as input and produces an **Result** as output:
[image]
In the desired refinement, I want to I want to access the children or create the result from the result parts.

### Current Solution

If I want to access the children or create the result from the result parts, I always have to introduce extra activities for those rather simple tasks:
[image]

### Question

Are there any shortcut or simplification here, to access, extract or merge the children of an object? The desired Solution should be legal standard UML.

Something as simple like this would be nice:
[image]

Comment: What exactly are the reasons why you consider the last diagram as "non legal UML!!"? Why did you put the `join` control node before the "merge result children" activity instead of modeling it as an action with 3 input pins?

Comment: @xmojmr It didn't describe it in that much detail, but one can read it between the lines in the current solution: the activity **do A** expects a **Child A** as input. But in my non-legal solution it gets a **Parent** as input instead. The same is true for the output: **do A** produces a **Result part A** but is connected to a **Result**. Working with pins could indeed be a slightly more simple solution, but I'm not sure how to use them. While going deeper into pins I already found something that looks somehow like what I'm looking for...

Comment: I am not sure to understand your problem: it seems to me that you intend to represent structural features (composition) of your objects in your activity diagram. The activity diagram is purely behavioral. The more you can do is to [introduce OCL constraints](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6724115) on your activities but this would be specific to your UML tools. Of course, if your do A, do B and do C activies are different on a behavioral point of view, your solution is legal...

Answer (score 2):

UML does not define complex object creation element. If you need to construct result object which is composition of child objects, you have to present action. You should define action with resulting pin of composed type and input pins of child object types for each one. Action can start execution only if all input pins contain expected object. 
For separation of child object from composed object use transformation as it is described in Waog's answer.

In your current solution example remove join element before merge result Children action, and connect all object nodes to this action. Remove extract input Children action and use transformation.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer on how to split objects

I found an answer on how to split a composed object in Martin Fowlers UML distilled myself, after getting a hint from @xmojmr

The book states:
[image]
[image]
Source: [UML Distilled: A Brief Guide to the Standard Object Modeling Language
 By Martin Fowler - on Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=nHZslSr1gJAC&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=uml%20pins%20and%20transformations&source=bl&ots=V83RJXRD9H&sig=Nq6lRMYRH7sb9QKr9SmU12Mf784&hl=en&sa=X&ei=a4qyVN-2CYSHO8engagD&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=true)

I still don't know, if it's allowed to omit thos transformation-notes and just draw the pins and transitions!?

### Missing Answer on how to merge objects

I'm still missing the answer on how to merge objects to a composed objects without introducting a merge-activity.